How to finetune fasterrcnn mobilenet v3 as binary class
How to convert fasterrcnn_mobilenet_v3_large_fpn to binary class in PyTorch lightening. I've data loader as all as 1 label only and i want to use finetuned model for binary class rather training from scratch.
Currently it has 91 classes, Target is 2
class CocoDNN(L.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = models.detection.fasterrcnn_mobilenet_v3_large_fpn(weights="DEFAULT")
        self.metric = MeanAveragePrecision(iou_type="bbox",average="macro",class_metrics = True, iou_thresholds=[0.5, 0.75],extended_summary=True, backend="faster_coco_eval")  

    def forward(self, images, targets=None):
        return self.model(images, targets)

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        
        imgs, annot = batch
        filtered_imgs, filtered_annot = [], []
        for idx, img_b in enumerate(imgs):
            annot_b = annot[idx]
            if img_b!= None and len(annot_b['boxes'])>0:
                filtered_imgs.append(img_b)
                filtered_annot.append(annot_b)
        loss_dict = self.model(filtered_imgs, filtered_annot)
        losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())
        #print(loss_dict)
        batch_size = len(filtered_imgs)
        self.log('train_loss', losses, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True, batch_size=batch_size)
        return {'loss':losses}

